# How do I initialize an array of std::sets?

Tags: c++

I want to have an array of std::sets in C++.

```
std::set<GLuint> arrayOfSets[10];
if ( arrayOfSets[ 5 ].empty() ){
  // do whatever
}
```

Is the code above acceptable, or do I need to do something to initialize the sets in the array?

And would I be better off with a std::vector of sets than an array?

Comment: `std::set` default constructor create empty set. it is not different when create array of sets. and you can check for each set if empty. only problem to create array is when you don't have default constructor.

Comment: I see, I am new to C++.  The default constructor will automatically get called if I do std::set<GLuint> arrayOfSets[10] ?

Comment: I've edited the previous answer, but anyway it is right. for arrays you always call the default constructor.